# How to support html right click (context menu) in iPad safari browser?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, contextmenu, mobile-safari

I have a requirement where right click in an existing website needs be supported in iPad. By convention, right click is converted to long press event in touch enabled devices. I have tested in Chrome in Android devices and it worked while it's broken in Safari in iPad (iPad Air 2, 10.3). Just for reference, I was using this demo site:

http://wwwendt.de/tech/demo/jquery-contextmenu/demo/

Could this be a bug in Safari in iOS devices?

Comment: still looking for an answer to this question